# how to make above view background transparent/translucent in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I want to make a transparent/translucent background in jetpack compose. I am trying to make my own `BottomSheet` for my project. I cannot find the way of box above background color. When my custom Bottom Sheet open, I want to show behind item `transparent/translucent`.

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment(private val hideViewListener: HideViewListener) : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: HomeFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        setupView()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setupView() {
        binding.composeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                MainScreen(hideViewListener)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(hideViewListener: HideViewListener) {
    var enable by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 24.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Welcome to bottom sheet playground!",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = Color.White,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
            repeat(5) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        enable = !enable
                        hideViewListener.hideView(enable)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Click to show bottom sheet $it")
                }
            }
        }
        if (enable) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                Column {
                    repeat(10) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                        Text(text = "Hi Bottom Sheet $it", color = Color.Black)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Ouput**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: You can apply an alpha to the Box. Something like: `Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Black.copy(alpha= alpha))`

Comment: But which box should I use ?

Comment: The Box in the MainScreen

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks but it's not working.. can you please give me example?

Comment: Do you want to apply the translucent effect also to the content of the Column?

Comment: Noo I don't want in column.